# jplayer get current position played

Tags: jquery, html, jplayer

I'd like to get current number of played movie in jplayer.

For example in playlist I got 3 movies, and when lets say second is played then something is happeing.

All I found so far from documentation is:

```
var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
}, [
{
    title: "Big Buck Bunny Trailer",
    artist: "Blender Foundation",
    free: true,
    m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v"
},
{
    title: "Finding Nemo Teaser",
    artist: "Pixar",
    m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.m4v"
},
{
    title: "Incredibles Teaser",
    artist: "Pixar",
    m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Incredibles_Teaser.m4v"
}
], {
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "m4v",
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
}
```

);
And then

```
if(myPlaylist.play()=="0"){
    console.log("do something")
}
```

or

```
if(myPlaylist.play(0)){
    console.log("do something")
}
```

It doesnt work at all. If anyone could help me , that'd be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your question here

[jPlayer 2.2.0: display track title in separate div on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298432/jplayer-2-2-0-display-track-title-in-separate-div-on-page-load)

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) {
                    var current = myPlaylist.current,
                            playlist = myPlaylist.playlist;
                    $.each(playlist, function(index, obj) {

                        if (index == current) {
                                console.log(current)

                        }
                    });
                });
```